# Hide form for certain amount of days after it has been submitted once?

Tags: javascript, date, hide, show

I am trying to only show a modal on Sundays. Then I am trying to only let the user submit the form once until the next Sunday. So I have this to only show the element on Sunday:

```
    function test(){
     var rightNow = new Date();
     var day = rightNow.getDay();
     var Sunday = (day == 0);
     if(Sunday){
       document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper').style.display = 'block';
     } else {
       document.querySelector('.modal-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
     }
   }
```

But, I am curious if there is some code I can write to not let the modal show if the "Submit" button has been pushed on the form inside the modal. Something like:

```
if(submit === pushed) {
 //hide modal again until next Sunday
}
```

I'm sure this is a stupid question to most stackoverflow dev overlords, but some help would be greatly appreciated. Even being pointed to the right resources or technology to study would be great, too. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind that new Date comes from the user's computer.  Setting my local computer date to Sunday and visiting your page would show me the form, in that case.

Comment: That is a good point James. The form is just to log about how many viewers are watching a live stream. I would like to know a more accurate way to write a function with say a servers date or google's date. I did not know that Javascript's date function got its data from the local computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` to store there some information about button being pushed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Then you can get item from `localStorage` and check if there is your value stored. So you will be able to know if somebody clicked this button or not.
But this information would be reliable only until `localStorage` would be cleaned.

Comment: Interesting. I've never used localStorage. So, since there is "no expiration" on local storage items. I would store the value of the submit locally then write something like if(day == 0) { storage.removeItem(submit.value)}, and theoretically that would work?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks. Using localStorage was exactly what I needed to do, and my script works. Woohoo.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do this completely in the DOM, but I think a better solution would be by storing the information in the User's database record. (That's an assumption that you have a database storing User information)

Add a boolean in the Users table for "Button Click." When the user clicks the button, change the status to `TRUE` and reset it to `FALSE` every week.

If the `TRUE`, don't show the modal.

Comment: From the information I have received there is no user database. Anybody can go to this site on Sunday morning and watch a live stream. Though, this is a much more straightforward solution.